# Is Etruscan zivas "to live" a borrowing from some IE language?

Tags: etymology, comparative-linguistics, borrowing, reconstruction

The Etruscan zivas looks similar to PIE *gʷih₃wós and its decendants, like Greek zōós, Latin vīvus, Proto-Italic and Proto-Hellenic *gʷīwos. Is it known to be a borrowing from an IE language?

Comment: Do you have any authoritative evidence for such a word and its gloss? I don't mean a wikipedia entry, I mean a real publication.

Comment: @user6726 bonfante and bonfante (probably one of the most mainstream detailed descriptions) list ziva as "the dead, deceased". This is presumably based on the same inscription, but obviously the definition is the reverse (and a different part of speech)